# vertica database autostart not running

Tags: vertica

I have an installed vertica cluster with 3 hosts. I want to do autostart database when starting the hosts (when all hosts were shutdown and now I turn on them). At every host in /etc/init.d/ I added script myscript.sh:

```
sudo -u myuser /opt/vertica/bin/admintools -t start_db -d test
```

When I run this script manually, it works and database is starting. But when the script is launched at OS startup, the database does not start. In the adminTools.log log I don't see startup errors, I see only pexpecting vsql command... and All nodes in db test are in state DOWN

```
2020-06-08 16:42:08.526 agent/752:0x7f195dffb700 [vsql._just_connect] <INFO> pexpecting vsql command: /opt/vertica/bin/vsql --no-vsqlrc -n  -p 5433 -U myuser -h 192.168.0.5 test -P pager -A
2020-06-08 16:42:08.984 agent/752:0x7f195dffb700 [vsql._just_connect] <INFO> pexpecting vsql command: /opt/vertica/bin/vsql --no-vsqlrc -n  -p 5433 -U myuser -h 192.168.0.6 test -P pager -A
2020-06-08 16:42:09.459 agent/752:0x7f195dffb700 [vsql._just_connect] <INFO> pexpecting vsql command: /opt/vertica/bin/vsql --no-vsqlrc -n  -p 5433 -U myuser -h 192.168.0.7 test -P pager -A
2020-06-08 16:43:05.639 admintools/3701:0x7f456298c740 [adminExec.getCollapsedClusterState] <INFO> All nodes in db test are in state DOWN
```

Why is that?

Comment: What's the OS? Under RHEL/Centos the vertica rpm package installs a systemd service unit called `verticad` which can be enabled.

Comment: Yes, My OS is Centos 7

Answer (score 0):

Yes, my OS is Centos 7

But service verticad doesn't work

I run `systemctl start verticad`

Then I run: `systemctl status verticad`

```
verticad.service - Vertica server restart oneshot
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/verticad.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2020-06-11 07:19:43 MSK; 38min ago
Process: 650 ExecStart=/opt/vertica/sbin/verticad start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 650 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

    Jun 11 07:19:09 verticaserv1 systemd[1]: Starting Vertica server restart oneshot...
    Jun 11 07:19:13 verticaserv1 su[706]: (to mydba) root on none
    Jun 11 07:19:43 verticaserv1 verticad[650]: Vertica: start OK for users: mydba
    Jun 11 07:19:43 verticaserv1 verticad[650]: [  OK  ]
    Jun 11 07:19:43 verticaserv1 systemd[1]: Started Vertica server restart oneshot.
```

In logs (/opt/vertica/log/verticad.log and /var/log/messages) I see only:

```
vertica process is not running
Vertica: start not OK
```

Comment: It is normal for systemd `oneshot` services to be reported as inactive once started.Your `start` command seems to have worked correctly, do you now see your db as UP in `admintools`?